# How to Redirect/Forward data from Spring MVC Controller to other page as POST?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, coldfusion

I'm working on a project which is a mix Spring MVC and coldfusion, I want to know how to redirect from the SpringMVC Controller to the cfm using a POST request.

I have this mapping defined

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/preprocess", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
   public ModelAndView doPreprocess(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam Map<String, String> params, HttpSession session) {
        //retrieve some parameters from db and redirect/forward here to "/postprocess.cfm"
   }
```

After retrieve some parameters, I need to redirect/forward those parameter to other endpoint "/postprocess.cfm", this page reads the params from a **form**, so the request to this page needs to be a POST

Looking forward to your help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By definition, you cannot redirect a POST. What you can do is send the parameters to the `/postprocess.cfm` serverside via HTTP POST request (`HttpClient`) from your `doPreprocess`. You can then process the response in your Spring App and dispatch from there.